# devenv only loading solutions if I supply full path

Tags: visual-studio-2010, devenv

I have a folder c:\TestSolution that contains a VS2010 solution TestSolution.sln.

If I'm on the command line (with appropriate vcvars.bat file already run), and I type `C:\TestSolution>devenv TestSolution.sln` I get the following popup:

[image]

However, if I supply the full path it loads correctly. E.g. `C:\TestSolution>devenv c:\TestSolution\TestSolution.sln` works.

In previous work environments, I didn't have to supply the full path, so I'm not sure what's up.

Any ideas?

Comment: That is strange.  It works just fine for me.

Comment: Yeah, I'm sure there is a setting somewhere in the registry that controls the behavior I just don't know what it would be, nor do I have access to SysInternal to monitor registry accesses as I load devenv... hoping someone can clue me in to the cause of this. 

It is hugely annoying.

Comment: I was going to suggest SysInternals actually.  How come you can't use that?

Comment: Not approved software ;( At the moment, I'm in one of those draconian "secure" environments where all software needs to be approved for use.

Comment: meh, forgoing `devenv` and just opening the solution c:\TestSolution>TestSolution.sln passes to the VSLauncher app and opens the solution with version the solution is for... so that is a good work around... but it is still annoying that my old habit of typing 'devenv solution.sln' doesn't work ;(